# Improper Translation Matrix from SVD of Essential Matrix for 3D reconstruction using 2 Images

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, 3d-reconstruction, pose-estimation

I am trying to find a 3D model from 2 images taken from the same camera using OpenCV with C++. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431047/3d-reconstruction-from-two-calibrated-cameras-where-is-the-error-in-this-pipel?rq=1) method. I am still not able to rectify mistake in R and T computation.

Image 1: With Background Removed for eliminating mismatches

[image: img]

Image 2: Translated  only in X direction wrt Image 1 With Background Removed for eliminating mismatches

[image: img]

I have found the Intrinsic Camera Matrix (K) using MATLAB Toolbox. I found it to be :

**K=**

> ```
> [3058.8    0    -500
>
> 0       3057.3   488
>
> 0       0         1]
> ```

All image matching keypoints (using SIFT and BruteForce Matching, Mismatches Eliminated) were aligned wrt center of image as follows:

```
obj_points.push_back(Point2f(keypoints1[symMatches[i].queryIdx].pt.x - image1.cols / 2, -1 * (keypoints1[symMatches[i].queryIdx].pt.y - image1.rows / 2)));
scene_points.push_back(Point2f(keypoints2[symMatches[i].trainIdx].pt.x - image1.cols / 2, -1 * (keypoints2[symMatches[i].trainIdx].pt.y - image1.rows / 2)));
```

From Point Correspondeces, I found out Fundamental Matrix Using RANSAC in OpenCV

**Fundamental Matrix:**

> ```
> [0             0      -0.0014
>  
> 0              0       0.0028
>
> 0.00149    -0.00572      1  ]
> ```

**Essential Matrix** obtained using:

```
E = (camera_Intrinsic.t())*f*camera_Intrinsic;
```

**E obtained:**

> ```
> [ 0.0094        36.290       1.507
>
> -37.2245        -0.6073      14.71
>
> -1.3578         -23.545     -0.442]
> ```

**SVD of E:**

```
E.convertTo(E, CV_32F);
Mat W = (Mat_<float>(3, 3) << 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
Mat Z = (Mat_<float>(3, 3) << 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

SVD decomp = SVD(E);
Mat U = decomp.u;
Mat Lambda = decomp.w;
Mat Vt = decomp.vt;
```

**New Essential Matrix for epipolar constraint:**

```
Mat diag = (Mat_<float>(3, 3) << 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
Mat new_E = U*diag*Vt;

SVD new_decomp = SVD(new_E);

Mat new_U = new_decomp.u;
Mat new_Lambda = new_decomp.w;
Mat new_Vt = new_decomp.vt;
```

**Rotation from SVD:**

```
Mat R1 = new_U*W*new_Vt;
Mat R2 = new_U*W.t()*new_Vt;
```

**Translation from SVD:**

```
Mat T1 = (Mat_<float>(3, 1) << new_U.at<float>(0, 2), new_U.at<float>(1, 2), new_U.at<float>(2, 2));
Mat T2 = -1 * T1;
```

I was getting the R matrices to be :

**R1:**

> ```
> [ -0.58      -0.042     0.813
> -0.020       -0.9975    -0.066
>  0.81        -0.054     0.578]
> ```

**R2:**

> ```
> [  0.98     0.0002      0.81
>   -0.02      -0.99      -0.066
>   0.81      -0.054      0.57 ]
> ```

**Translation Matrices:**

**T1:**

> [0.543
>
> -0.030
>
> 0.838]

**T2:**

> [-0.543
>
> 0.03
>
> -0.83]

Please clarify wherever there is a mistake.

This 4 sets of P2 matrix R|T with P1=[I] are giving incorrect triangulated models.

Also, I think the T matrix obtained is incorrect, as it was supposed to be only x shift and no z shift.

When tried with same image1=image2 -> I got T=[0,0,1]. What is the meaning of Tz=1? (where there is no z shift as both images are same)

And should I be aligning my keypoint coordinates with image center, or with principle focus obtained from calibration?

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that the two images are planer which means that the result will be a simple plane?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Yes I am aware (I am in primary testing stage -simple translation, rotation of simple shapes ), The result will be planar - It is expected that depth values will be same for all points, but this wasn't the outcome of actual triangulation.

Comment: I think the Essential matrix needs to be estimated from points in general configuration. The translation will then be estimated up to a scale factor.  You better check the literature, for instance: [Relationships between the Homography and the Essential Matrix](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/sp04/cse252b/notes/lec05/lec5.pdf)